# Set amount of memory available to AppFabric Caching

Tags: .net, asp.net, caching, configuration, appfabric

How do I set the amount of memory available to the Windows Server AppFabric Caching service?

We're running the AppFabric Cache on the same server which is hosting the website, and I'd like to be able to control how much RAM the cache will consume.

Comment: I am not sure this is possible.. Looking forward to a better answer :)

Comment: wow - I have 2 users sessionstate for just testing and it took 700MB!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can modify the amount of ram available using this commands on the powerShell console:

```
Stop-cachecluster
Set-cacheHostConfig {Machine name} {port(22233)} -CacheSize {cache allocation in MB}
Start-cachecluster
```

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790935.aspx)

Comment: Works. Set-CacheHostConfig PLUTO 22233 -CacheSize 1024.

Comment: if it appears to timeout you may need elevated permissions